# Convert graphics object to bitmap object

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

How can I convert graphics object to bitmap object using C#?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Draw on `Graphics` object and save as image file?

Answer (score 23):

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, myGraphics);
```

Alternatively:

```
Graphics myGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
// some code with draw on myGraphics
myGraphics.Dispose();
```

Comment: `new Bitmap(.., my Graphics)` does **not** copy the pixels of the graphics into the bitmap, nor otherwise give access to the contents of `myGraphics`.  The second solution is a solution to a different problem (somewhat the opposite of what was asked): how to draw into a bitmap using `Graphics` methods.

Comment: Once I created a [`ToBitmap`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_GraphicsExtensions_ToBitmap.htm) extension exactly for this purpose. [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing/) and [source](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing) are both available. Remark: the `ToBitmap` extension works on Windows only.

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean `System.Drawing.Graphics` ? The Graphics class is a surface to an image and is already a bitmap.

What are you trying to do with it ?

```
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
  //draw here
}
```

or

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100,100,graphics);
```

Comment: The docs just say *The Graphics object that specifies the resolution for the new Bitmap.*; doesn't quite sound like anything from the `Graphics` object is copied.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you might want: [DaniWeb](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet217221.html#), yes annoyingware but it does provide a working solution